# ndarray contained in pandas dataframe is not copied when using df.copy()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Dataframe df1 with column 'a'.
each row in column 'a' contains a 2d numpy array

```
> df1 
                                               a
0  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
1  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
2  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
3  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
```

I want to create a copy of this Dataframe and make changes to the 2d arrays without effecting the arrays in df1

So I took an explicit deep copy

```
df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)
> df2
                                               a
0  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
1  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
2  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
3  [[10.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0,...
```

Now changing a value in the array in the first cell of df2 is also effecting df1

```
df2.loc[0,'a'][0,0] = 0
> df2
                                              a
0  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...
1  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...
2  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...
3  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...

> df1
                                              a
0  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...
1  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...
2  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...
3  [[0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, ...
```

How can I avoid this and what is the best way to make a copy of all sub objects of a Dataframe?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [pandas documentations says](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

> Note that when copying an object containing Python objects, a deep copy will copy the data, but will not do so recursively. Updating a nested data object will be reflected in the deep copy.

You have a 2d numpy array in each column.

To create a new deep copy recursively you can create another dataframe using copy.deepcopy for the data.

```
df2= pd.DataFrame(data=copy.deepcopy(df1.values), columns=df1.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are one of two columns with mutable data (in the current case, `ndarray`) structure, then I usually prefer the following method,

```py
df_new = df.copy()
df_new['the_col'] = df_new['the_col'].map(np.copy)
```